# Tool to trace mac address back to a switch port

Tags: mac, snmp, switch

To make a long story short, I have some newer off-brand switches in just a few locations.  The main feature I'm missing on these switches vs our nicer (but old) 3Com equipment is the ability to trace a mac address down to a specific port in the address tables.  The off-brand switches do support snmp.  Can someone recommend a good (and cheap/free) software tool (probably snmp-based) that will allow me to trace a mac address down to a specific switch port?

Comment: make/model please?

Comment: There's 3 different model switches - one netgear, one dlink, and one (sigh) tplink.  I'm hoping for something generic that pulls the info via snmp.

Comment: What do you mean by "off-brand"?

Comment: I mean a brand that's traditionally more consumer focused rather than top-tier enterprise like cisco or 3com/hp.

Comment: That 3Com feature was very good; CPU by port is a lifesaver sometimes too..

Answer (score 3):

Are there cli tools?  You could do something like (I know it's cisco, bear with me):

```
switch>ping 192.168.101.1

Type escape sequence to abort.
Sending 5, 100-byte ICMP Echos to 192.168.101.1, timeout is 2 seconds:
!!!!!
Success rate is 100 percent (5/5), round-trip min/avg/max = 1/1/1 ms
```

Then search the arp for the IP:

```
switch>show arp | include 101.1
Internet  192.168.101.12         37   0020.6b61.a83d  ARPA   Vlan101
Internet  192.168.101.1           -   001d.09fd.71c0  ARPA   Vlan101
```

Now that you know the MAC address, search the mac address table:

```
switch>show mac-address-table | include 71c0
*    1  000d.662f.71c0    static  No           -   Router
*   10  001d.09fd.71c0   dynamic  Yes         20   Gi2/43
```

Voila! Port 43 on the second internal switch.

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea whether or not [Netdisco](http://www.netdisco.org/) supports your devices, but that's the tool I've turned to in the past for keeping track of the physical location of MAC addresses on my networks.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with him, you need to find the mac address first, and look for it ini your 3Com switch.

I have 3Com SuperStack III 4200 series, you need to login to your switch, and use these command: bridge --> addressDatabase --> summary to display all mac address on your switch.

Comment: I can do that on the 3Coms... this question about how to do it on the non-3Com switches that don't have that feature.